# Can PCA be used for independent variables?

Tags: pca, supervised-learning

Currently I've been carrying out a research on prediction of some thermal properties of steels from chemical composition only. For that purpose I have 13 inputs (for instance: C,Mn,Ni, etc). They are totally independent. If I apply a PCA analysis, 94.8% of the variance can be explained by 10 components, and my results improve largely,since I have few data points. The question that arises is: does the PCA analysis make sense for such situation? My intention was to perform a bias/variance trade-off, however I don't know if it is conceptually incorrect to use PCA in such case.

Comment: I don't buy "totally independent" for steel composition. At a minimum the constraint that the total is 1 or 100% needs consideration.

Comment: Were the inputs standardised before being put into PCA? If not, PCA will just tell you which components have the largest variances, which you already know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question and the comments and answer given, it seems that you are free to set the composition of steel at will and want to see what difference it makes in some thermal properties. Sounds to me as an experimental design problem. I do not see a role for PCA here.

Answer (score 2):

- In what way is what you are doing related to supervised learning? PCA does not require labels/outcomes.
- If you have 13 variables and 94 % of the variance can be explained by 10 components... then you haven't done much, may as well keep the 13 columns.
- In what way do your results "improve largely"? One would expect the new model to perform at most as good as the original model and not better, given that PCAs' main goal is feature reduction.
- There is one limitation (assumption) of PCA, and that is that it can capture linear correlations between the variables. Given that your variables are "totally independent", then I don't see the point of PCA in this case.

Comment: the fact it's a supervised learning problem was just displayed to detail what I am doing. It's not important at all, as you've just mentioned. I obtained a improvement of 8% in the test set. As you stated, PCA basic assumption is the ability to capture correlations amoung variables, however,since the fact that applying it to independent variables did result in a better performance, I am curious to know if it was just a coincidence or not.

Comment: @corsetti This will be hard to answer without knowing exactly what you did after PCA. There are multiple cases which would result in better performance on a model built on PCA-d data. First option is of course 1) data leakage, 2) could be just chance, 3) standardized variables vs nonstandardized in PCA vs supervised learning model, 4) if you have a very small sample, and you have managed to make the problem a little more manageable by decreasing the number of variables to increase the performance a little bit.

Comment: @corsetti how do you know the variables are "totally independent"?

Comment: @user2974951 after applying PCA to the normalized inputs, they were fed to a Neural Network. As you said in 4), the dataset is quite small, and reducing the input features definitely made the problem more feasible, however I am uncertain if PCA can be used in such a way. It's not because it worked that it's correct, however when it does work we feel tempted to accept it.

Comment: @elliotp the chemical composition of a steel can be chosen freely, so it's hard to assume some dependence among them.

Comment: @corsetti if what you have is a complete compositional analysis of the samples, then there is an inherent dependence among the components as their fractional contributions to the composition must add up to 1. It's not clear from your question whether that is the case here. If it is, there is a whole field of [compositional data analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositional_data) to deal with that type of dependence.

Comment: @EdM you are right, however I've already taken that into account. I just omitted the composition of one element (iron) to avoid this situation